# amdgpu drivers broke debian APT

Tags: debian, apt, amd, amdgpu

Each time I try to use APT I get this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 clinfo-amdgpu-pro : Depends: ocl-icd-libopencl1-amdgpu-pro but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

If I try `sudo apt --fix-broken install` it gives me this:

```
Unpacking ocl-icd-libopencl1-amdgpu-pro:amd64 (21.40.1-1337803) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ocl-icd-libopencl1-amdgpu
-pro_21.40.1-1337803_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/opt/amdgpu-pro/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so.1', whic
h is also in package libopencl1-amdgpu-pro:amd64 17.40-492261
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ocl-icd-libopencl1-amdgpu-pro_21.40.1-1337803_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this command:

```
sudo dpkg --purge ocl-icd-libopencl1-amdgpu-pro
```

Comment: Please explain what this does and how it answers the question.   Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.